# Why charge per unit length is taken to determine capacitance of cylindrical capacitor?

Tags: capacitance

To determine the capacitance of a cylindrical capacitor why charge per unit length is taken? The charge is uniformly distributed on the surface of the inner cylinder. So charge per unit area should be taken. Why there is charge per unit length?

Comment: It isn't. It's used to determine the capacitance per unit length, instead.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that even if you express the charge as surface charge density you are still left in your expression for the capacitance $C$ with a factor of $\ell$, the length of the cylinder, so that physically the result is that a cylinder twice as long would have roughly twice the capacitance (exactly $2\times$ if we neglect fringing.)

This is because $C=Q/\Delta V$ and $Q$ increases with the length $\ell$ of your cylinder whereas $\Delta V$ does not depend on $\ell$ since the field of a cylinder is everywhere perpendicular to this axis of the cylinder and thus independent of $\ell$.

By Gauss' law
$$
\oint \vec E\cdot d\vec S= \frac{q_{encl}}{\epsilon}= E(\rho) 2\pi \rho \ell
$$
where $\rho$ is the distance in cylindrical coordinates from the wire and thus the radius of the Gaussian cylinder, while $\ell$ is the length of the Gaussian cylinder.  Hence one sees that
$$
E(\rho)= \frac{q_{encl}}{\ell} \frac{1}{2\pi  \epsilon \rho}
$$
and what matters in computing the field, and thus computing the potential, is $\frac{q_{encl}}{\ell} $, i.e. the charge per length.   For a cylindrical capacitor of inner radius $\rho_0$ and outer radius $\rho_1$, one then finds 
$$
\Delta V = \frac{q_{encl}}{2\pi\epsilon \ell}\log \left(\rho_1/\rho_0\right)
$$
One can further simplify using
$$
q_{encl}= \sigma 2\pi \rho_0 \ell\, ,\qquad 
\frac{q_{encl}}{\ell}=\sigma 2\pi \rho_0
$$
so that 
$$
\Delta V=  \frac{\sigma 2\pi \rho_0 }{2\pi\epsilon}\log \left(\rho_1/\rho_0\right) = \sigma\frac{\rho_0}{\epsilon}\log\left(\rho_1/\rho_0\right) \tag{1}
$$
So far so good as (1) does not depend on the length; the issue arises because the capacitance is the * net charge* divided by the voltage difference, but this net charge is proportional to the length of the cylinder:
$$
C=\frac{Q}{\Delta V}=\frac{\sigma 2\pi \rho_0\ell}{\Delta V}
=\frac{\sigma 2\pi \rho_0\ell}{\Delta V}
=\frac{\sigma \ell\epsilon}{\log(\rho_1/\rho_0)}
$$
where $2\pi\rho_0\ell$ is the area of the inner cylinder of radius $\rho_0$ of your capacitor so that $Q=\sigma 2\pi\rho_0\ell$ is the charge on the cap.  As predicted, the capacitance increase with $\ell$ because the net charge $Q$ increases with $\ell$ while the potential difference, given in (1), does not depend on this factor.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at it, the inner cylinder of the capacitor is just ***like a wire*** which has charge distributed uniformly throughout it.

So, in order to get the E. field between the plates, consider a cylindrical gaussian surface of length y and radius smaller than the outer plate and larger than the inner plate.

Then the charge inside that gaussian surface will be given by,

$q=\frac{Q}{L}y$

If a cylinder of length $L$ contains of charge $Q$, then a cylinder of unit length will contain charge $\frac{Q}{L}$. Therefore, a cylinder of length $y$, will contain charge  $\frac{Q}{L}y$.

Neglecting the fringing effect, The electric flux through the curved part of the gaussian surface will be given by,

$\phi=\int\vec{E}.\vec{ds}=\int E.ds.\cos{90^{\circ}}=E\int ds=E.2\pi ry$

Thus, $\phi=E.2\pi ry=\frac{Q}{\epsilon_{\circ}}(\frac{y}{L})$

$E=\frac{Q}{2\pi \epsilon_{\circ}Lr}$

Potential difference is,

$V_b-V_a=-\int_{a}^{b}\frac{Q}{2\pi \epsilon_{\circ}Lr}dr$

From here, you will get the value of $V$, i.e, the potential difference between the plates,

$C=\frac{Q}{V}$

And finally,

> $C=\frac{2\pi \epsilon_{\circ}L}{ln(\frac{b}{a})}$

Answer (score 0):

I think that if the assumption is made that the surface charge density is uniform it is just a matter of convenience to use charge per unit length particularly if you take the Gaussian surface to be a concentric cylinder.
If $\lambda$ is the charge per unit length and $\sigma$ is the charge per unit area on the inner conductor of radius $a$ then the charge on a length $L$ of the conductor $Q = \lambda L = \sigma 2\pi a L$.
So why bother to write $\sigma 2\pi a$ when $\lambda$ will do?

A reason for using surface charge density might be if the Gaussian surface was chosen to be wedge shaped like a slice of cake although the derivation could still be performed using charge per unit length.

Another possible reason for using charge per unit length is that for the inner and outer conductor the charge per unit length would be the same whereas the surface charge density would not.